# Easy - can't move nav to the right

Tags: css

I'm learning css and some things just won't ever work for me. Is it normal that I just have to mess around with the code for hours on, just to get something looking exactly how I want it to?

My problem is that I cant move the nav bar to the right of my wrapper.

site: http://www.e2-repair.be

This is the code I got:

```
header {
    height: 100px;

}

header #header-cont {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Sofadi One', cursive;
    }

header img {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}

header h1 {
    font-size:32px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}

header nav{
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    height:100px;
}

header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Tried a lot of things such as float, margins etc..

Answer (score 0):

Dont use flex, its not nearly browser compatible!

Alter these two ;)

```
header #header-cont {
    widt*h: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Sofadi One', cursive;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Right now I'm just using it for educational purposes. I understand I can make it work easily without that but I would prefer to get to know the new techniques. I'm just quite stuck with this one..

Comment: The 'new techniques' are not supported!

Comment: Isn't flex supported by most of the latest browsers

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex Browsersupport doesn't mean that Elements in relation to that, work the same. But why not lear the basics when they're easy, jump right for the advanced...